# Redirect User to Signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Using `before_action :authenticate_user!` to check if user logged in. But it sends users to `login` instead of `signup`.

Tried different ways of directing user to `signup` instead of `login`, but they do not **send the user back to the original page after successful signup**.

How can I send a user to signup and direct a user back to the original page afterwards?

Attempts:

```
before_filter :auth_user

def auth_user
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url unless user_signed_in?
end
```

#### Routes File

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :installs
  resources :orders
  resources :products
  devise_for :users

  get 'dashboard' => 'pages#dashboard'
  get 'contact' => 'pages#contact'
  get 'cart' => 'carts#index'

  root 'pages#home'
```

Comment: what's in your routes file ?

Comment: @Nithin added routes file

Comment: This page got the solution to your needs, [how to redirect back to current page after sign_up](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update)

Comment: Found this one way simpler [How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)) which seems pretty much easier. When it says `/an/example/path` you should use the prefix `:back`.

Comment: Seems like problem is in application controller, just curious to see all your before filter calls. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [`referer`](http://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Request/referer).
Having your before_filter working, you can override the Devise's `after_sign_up_path_for`:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
  request.referer
end
```

---

## EDIT

Since `request.referer` is somehow not working, I think you could go with a session-based solution:

```
def auth_user
  session[:before_sign_up_path] = request.fullpath
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url unless user_signed_in?
end

def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
  session[:before_sign_up_path]
end
```

Comment: I put `def after_sign_up_path_for` in the same controller as the `before_filter`. It is still not redirecting to referrer after signup.

Comment: `after_sign_up_path_for` should be defined in either `ApplicationController` or in a controller, which inherits from `Devise::RegistrationsController`

Comment: I tried moving it to ApplicationController with `def after_sign_up_path_for(user)` and `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)`. Still not redirecting to referrer. I've also tried this method: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration) but got error `[GET] User route was not defined`.

Comment: can you debug if the method is being called? define it as I suggested, put `binding.pry` as a first line of method and see, if your logs will show the console. if yes, please check the value of `request.referer` there

Comment: Looks like when I use `ApplicationController` it never gets called. But when create `Registration_Controller` and define the route (see the link above), it gets called. However, I run into the error `No route matches [GET] "/users"` after I `continue` on `binding.pry`

Comment: Looks like just calling `request.referer` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: when you are in the `binding.pry` console, what does `request.referer` outputs? Is it nil or what? ooooh, sorry! see the edit

Comment: Oh the `request.referer` is pointing to the signup page: `"http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up"`

Comment: ok, then referer obviously is not working.. (I have no idea why though).  I think I can come up with a session based solution.

Comment: please see the edit, I hope you get the idea and it will work for you

Answer (score 2):

Devise uses warden for authentication. Thus to override the whole behavior you have to override the way `devise` asks it to handle authentication failures.

**Create a class that extends `Devise::FailureApp`**

```
class RedirectToSignUp < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
     new_user_registration_url
  end

  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

**Add this to your `devise` initializer `config/initializers/devise.rb`**

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = RedirectToSignUp
end
```

I believe this will solve your problem and will redirect you to the page you were at since you are overriding only the redirect route.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update) seems to be what you are looking for. Note that it says that it is out of date. So you should see the source code if you want to understand what's going on.

Navigating through the source code of Devise([this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/store_location.rb) and [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L23)) my guess is that you can extend `Devise::RegistrationsController` and then override the method `after_sign_up_path_for` to be `stored_location_for(:user) || root_path`.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example? I tried this but it hard codes the redirect to a specific page (not necessarily back to the original page).

Answer (score 0):

the way I like to set up my users area using devise is:

```
  # config/routes.rb
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    sessions: "users/sessions",
    passwords: 'users/passwords',
    confirmations: 'users/confirmations'
  }

  authenticate :provider do
    namespace :providers do
      ....
    end
  end
```

Then I have a controller that manages all other users controllers  like this

```
#app/controllers/user_controller.rb
class UserController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  layout 'users/default'
  before_filter :check_user_active

  private
  def check_user_active
    unless current_user.active
      flash[:notice]= t(:user_not_active)
      sign_out current_user
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

all my other user controllers look inherit from it like

```
#app/controllers/users/users_controller.rb
class Users::UsersController < UserController
  ...
end
```

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

## This is very simple

#### User `store_location_for` method

Like

```
before_filter :auth_user

def auth_user
  unless user_signed_in?
    store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url 
  end
end
```