# Rails: Redirect to sign up instead of sign in when requiring login in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

When you add

`before_action :authenticate_user!`

in any controller the actions of that controller redirect to log in page if you are not signed in, however how to redirect to sign up path instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

in controller means, you use the inherited method from [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise).

To make it perform in any way, that differs from original implementation you have to to override it.

To do so you just define the method in controller and change the behavior to whatever you want.

In your case the closest to your needs would be:

```
def authenticate_user!
  redirect_to(new_user_registration_path, alert: 'Your custom message here') unless user_signed_in?
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks!, however I have a redirect to `request.referer` once user sings up using `after_sign_up_path_for` and after add your snippet it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: @SsouLlesS I am not sure I got you right, but [here's another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883697/redirect-user-to-signup) I answered recently which had similar issue. May be you'll find it useful?

Comment: Thanks!! it was very useful!!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko It is redirecting infinitely and see the log `Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add authenticate_user! method to the application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :authenticate_user!        

    protected
    def authenticate_user!
        redirect_to new_user_registration_pah, notice: "You must login" unless user_signed_in?
    end
```